# Website for Groovy Katas

Tags: groovy

Am planning to learn Groovy the Kata way. Is there any source similar to RubyQuiz for Groovy Katas ?

Answer (score 6):

Also see http://github.com/nadavc/groovykoans for step-by-step Groovy tutorials, covering:

- Basic operators
- Groovy truth
- Groovy Beans
- Closures
- Iterations
- Regular expressions
- Meta programming (MOP)
- And more...

*Disclaimer: I wrote them ;)*

Comment: I like your koans very much, thank you for implementing and providing them!

Comment: Thanks @Nadav. I had to update the site link though, as the .org domain doesn't resolve.

Comment: http://nadavc.github.io/groovykoans/ looks to be the new location. @Nadav, can you update your answer?

Comment: Looks like the site is dead.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Philip. I haven't renewed the domain but forgot to remove the CNAME. It should work now (try cleaning the cache if not).

Comment: @Nadav I now see the problem, please update your link to be: https://github.com/nadavc/groovykoans - the one in your answer redirects to your .org, which says under construction.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the Groovy Koans at https://github.com/cjudd/groovy_koans.

Answer (score 2):

[Coding Kata](http://codingkata.org/) is a site that provides code katas and examples in several JVM languages, Groovy being one of them.

Unfortunately the Java-oriented Coding Kata site is offline. You can try [the .Net version](http://codingkata.net/)

Comment: This link http://codingkata.org/ does not exist anymore,  the domain is for sale.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend **[Groovy Metaprogramming Koans](http://osoco.github.com/groovy-metakoans/)**.

It's an awesome source to learn about Metaprogramming with Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Take any quiz and implement it in the language of choice. There are a lot of cases: some guy solved PythonChallenge almost completely in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

I have enjoyed solving math problems with Groovy, Kotline etc. at the Euler Project site -> http://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score 0):

A pretty decent site for Koans 
http://www.groovy-koans.org/